# How to restore Regolith i3xrocks status bar

Tags: 20.04, i3-wm, tiling

Here is what I did to mess things up.  I followed the process of removing regolith as this was during an upgrade of Ubuntu 18 to 20.04

1. Install `regolith-desktop-complete` with `apt install regolith-desktop-complete`
2. The status bar had too many items so I started removing config files from `/etc/regolith/i3xrocks/conf.d`
3. The status bar got really messed up so I deleted all files from `/etc/regolith/i3xrocks/conf.d`

I have followed the process to apt purge regolith and remove all i3xrocks related packages.  After reinstalling I still have an empty `/etc/regolith/i3xrocks/conf.d` directory and no status bar.

Could anyone advise on how to completely start from scratch with regolith desktop?   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. I completely uninstalled Regolith using `apt purge regolith-*`
2. Delete ~/.config/regolith
3. Delete /etc/regolith

Reinstalled `apt install regolith-desktop-complete` now the status bar is back.